# How to make edit text as input pushbutton as output together with a msgbox in MATLAB gui

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I made a matlab gui where when user enter the value in the edit text and click on pushbutton the msgbox will popout. I tried this coding

```
    `if value >= 1 && value <= 40
  edit1String = sprintf('Your score is %f.\nYour skin is dry', value);
elseif value >= 41
 edit1String = sprintf('Your score is %f.\nYour skin is moist', value);
else
  rmdir('..');         %when the specifications do not say what is to happen, then the program is allowed to do ANYTHING
end`
```

and put it under edit text but nothing happened? I tried put it under pushbutton and nothing happen too. Anyone has any idea?

Comment: ... `else rmdir('..')` Are you sure?

Comment: i dont know...any idea???

Comment: Do you know [rmdir('..') does](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rmdir.html)?

Comment: i dont know.. i'm a beginner with matlab and also this is my first time using it so yeah...